# How to return value typescript

Tags: typescript

> I try to check value statusC and add new value for statusP with process:
> If all statusC = ACCEPTED => statusP = ACCEPTED, if  all statusC = REJECTED=> statusP = REJECTED, else status C have 2 value ACCEPTED and REJECTED = > StatusP = COMPLETED

1. Declare Enum type use all

```
enum Status {
    INPROGRESS = "INPROGRESS",
    ACCEPTED = "ACCEPTED",
    REJECTED= "REJECTED",
    COMPLETED = "COMPLETED"
}
```

2. Declare a:

```
let a= [
    {
    name:"test 1",
    statusP : Status.INPROGRESS,
    detail:[
        {
            nameC: "Test 2",
            statusC: Status.REJECTED
        },
        {
            nameC: "Test 3",
            statusC: Status.ACCEPTED
        }
    ]
    }
];
```

3. check statusC and add new value for statusP*

```
const checkStatusC = a[0].detail.map(
        (item)=>{
            let b;
            b =  item.statusC;
            if(b===Status.ACCEPTED){
                a[0].statusP = Status.ACCEPTED
            }else if (b === Status.REJECTED){
                a[0].statusP = Status.REJECTED
            } else if({?}){
                a[0].statusP = Status.COMPLETED
            }
        }
    )
```

Please have me condition at {?}

Comment: if statusC is inprogress than what will be statusP? @Cường Trần

Comment: if statusC is inprogress than statusP will be inprogresss. @JayPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `map` in this case, `map` is for mapping current items to new items (an array). If you want to set a new value or new values, you can use `reduce` instead.

```
a[0].statusP = a[0].detail.reduce(
        (result, item)=>{
            //stop further checking for status P
            if(result === Status.COMPLETED) {
                return result;
            }

            //the current result of status P is different from status C
            if(result && result !== Status.INPROGRESS && result !== item.statusC){
                result = Status.COMPLETED;
            } else {
                result = item.statusC; //REJECTED or ACCEPTED
            }
            return result;
        }
    , a[0].statusP) //default value from status P
```

You also can use the traditional iteration `for-of` which is more effective with a proper `break`.

```
for(const item of a[0].detail) {
    //the current result D is different from status C
    if(a[0].statusP && a[0].statusP !== Status.INPROGRESS && a[0].statusP !== item.statusC){
       a[0].statusP = Status.COMPLETED;
       break; //stop further checking
    } else {
       a[0].statusP = item.statusC; //REJECTED or ACCEPTED
    }
}
```